# unable to save generated rpt file into my local drive as a pdf

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

My code for save to my drive is like that

```
rdocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, ExportFilePath_1)
```

in that

ExportFilePath_1 =D:\TMS_WEB\Certificates\Certificate - 12-Jun-2015 - L1242_283.pdf

rdocument is the object of  ReportDocument

```
 rdocument = New ReportDocument
```

The error I get in catch is that

```
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\Certificate {410D5B3C-4B50-4372-A5B6-64174B8C8CC7}.rpt:
The specified value type is different to the current value type.
```

Comment: Are you sending any parameters to the report? Particularly dates?

Comment: ya there is mismatch of the parameter in report and procedure of that.
i alter the procedure and make changes regarding that...thank youh....